# Comparing two Key Value Dictionaries C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have two dictionaries

1 has the Dictionary A (expected values) and Dictionary B.

**They are both dictionaries, and I want to be able to say, if B.Keys contains a key from A, compare the two values and return true or false.**

How do I write something like this:

```
if (B.ContainsKey(A.Keys))
        {

        }
```

Example of Key Value:

```
Dictionary<Key, Value> B = {name, "valueb"; last, "smith"}
Dictionary<Key, Value> A = {name, "valuea"; last, "smith"; middle, "m"}

if (name == name) 
{
 if("valueb" == "valuea" )
{
 return false;
}
}
```

Comment: `if(list1.Any(list2.Contains))`

Comment: Do you want to compare all keys and only return true if the values of all the matching keys match? Or do you just want to compare a specific key?

Comment: @RufusL I want to compare a few keys, and if their values match, return true.

Comment: What do you mean by 'a few'? Do you mean of them, or do you have a list of keys you want to compare?

Comment: Also, what does your dictionary definition look like (what it the type of key and type of value)?

Comment: @RufusL, for instance before my if condition, I will have a  for (int i = 0; i < B.Count; i++) loop, then grab each B Key to compare to a static Dictionary A list. What essentially I am achieving is just go through check a list of Keys if they exist in the expected Keys, compare the Value.  If the Values match return true else false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scan one dictionary and lookup in second and compare like this:

```
var a = new Dictionary<TK,TV>();
var b = new Dictionary<TK,TV>();

var isEquals = a.All(x =>
{
    TV v;
    if (b.TryGetValue(x.Key, out v))
       return x.Value.Equals(v);

    return false;
});
```

**UPD**

```
isEquals = true;
foreach(x in a)
{
    TV v;
    if (b.TryGetValue(x.Key, out v))
       isEquals = isEquals && x.Value.Equals(v);
    else
    {
       isEquals = false;
       break;
    }

}
```

Comment: is there another option to use then ALL?  When one Value does not equal, the loop stops and I want it to continue through the rest.  I know Any will stop at the first Value.Equal, but I want it to still continue through.

Comment: @epv, yes it can be rewriten as loop, any is minimal required to get is a totaly equals b. I updated answer

Comment: Thank you @gabba, I have not seen the update so maybe it's taking some time.

Comment: foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> x in a)
                string v;
                if (b.TryGetValue(x.Key, out v))
                {
                       if (x.Value.ToLower() == v.ToLower())
                        { match = true;}

                        else
                        {match = false}
                }
                else
                {match = false}
                return match;
            });   Only looks through the first element.

Comment: @epv, because you make a return by a last line in loop. You have to rewrite loop correctly